# spl_autoload_register fails when load classes

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

So the structure of my project is the following:

```
- Project
   - php
      - classes
          - Config.php
          - DB.php
      - core
          - init.php
      - index.php
```

In my **core/init.php** file, I use *spl_autoload_register()* to load the different classes:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    require_once 'classes/' .$class. '.php';
});
```

And for test reasons, in **index.php**, I require my **init.php** file and try a method of my DB class:

```
require_once 'php/core/init.php'; 
$_db = DB::getInstance();
```

But I just get nothing. I am sure the issue is the PHP because when I only have html in **index.php**, everything's work.

Where is the issue? I assume it is from *spl_autoload_register()* which, somehow fail to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your autoloader to this:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../classes/' .$class. '.php';
});
```

So are you sure that it includes the file from the correct location.

Comment: Works perfectly. For those who wants to know: I was using a docker container which for some reasons messed up the path. Many thanks!